# TFS Markdown code syntax highlighting

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, markdown

I've got a Git repository running in TFS (on premises) and based on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance) I should be able to highlight my code using the following syntax:

````
``` sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Project
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Project PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProjectId);
```
````

However I end up getting this:
[image]

Do I have to install some sort of extension or enable something in settings in order to have proper code highlighting?

Version 16.122.27102.1

Comment: Where do you want to use the Markdown file? Code, dashboard wiki or any other places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the Code highlighting on my side with the sql syntax string you mentiond above and it works as expected.

If you mean use the Markdown in repository (Code) or wiki or dashboard, then you don't need any other extensions, it's built-in feature.

But note that code will not be highlighted with the syntax in **Dashboard**, it's the expected behavior.

In Git repository or wiki, the Code highlighting works as expected.

If you want enable Markdown in work items, then you can install the [Markdown extension here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschleiden.markdown)

> Markdown is a custom work item form control, that allows you to edit the rich text fields on your work items with a Markdown enabled editor.

---

**UPDATE:**

For now in repository it's only supported on VSTS. Not supported yet on premises TFS. But in wiki both are supported.

[image]

Comment: That's quite strange. I've got this in my repository. Could this require some extra features enabled? Also, is this running on premises or is hosted by M$?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas For now in repository it's just supported on VSTS. Not supported yet on premises TFS. But in wiki both are supported.